# Function will not return multiple returns - multiple-value in single-value context

Tags: go

Go refuses to return multiple returns. If I leave out the second return it works but I need the second return. How do I resolve?

Here is my call:

```
type Streaming struct{}

func main() {
    mySlice, dateList = getHgetallStreamingData()
}
```

Here is my function:

```
func getHgetallStreamingData(pair string, c redis.Conn) ([]Streaming, []time.Time) {    
    var mySlice []Streaming
    var dateList []time.Time
    return mySlice, dateList
 }
```

Here is my error:

```
multiple-value getHgetallStreamingData() in single-value context
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is from the line where you assign the results to two variables? Check the line number of the compiler error.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the error might be coming from somewhere else.  That is valid code.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/RlDhETI84Gh my guess is you're passing the result straight to another function call that accepts either 1 argument, more than 2 arguments or N+1 arguements together with a variadic argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error must be coming from somewhere else. The code works like a charm:

```
package main

import "time"

type Streaming struct{}

func main() {
    _, _ = getHgetallStreamingData()
}

func getHgetallStreamingData() (s []Streaming, t []time.Time) {
    return
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.com/p/AM6IJ-GV79A).